# Adding data to a tree-view-list

Tags: java, android, treeview

I've started to use the tree-view-list to show my data.  The tree-view-list can be found here:

http://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/

The code that adds text to the tree view line is this:

```
private String getDescription(final long id) {
    final Integer[] hierarchy = getManager().getHierarchyDescription(id);
    return "Node " + id + Arrays.asList(hierarchy);

}
```

in the SimpleStandardAdapter.java file. The data shown in the demo is based on the row id and nothing external to the treeview.

How would I go about adding text for a line of the tree that is external to the tree view?

For example, an array of data that is filled at run time.

Comment: Hi Michael, have you succeded in this or not?? Could you help me out in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adapter (pretty much as any other adapter) build views from the data provided by model. The AbstractTreeViewAdapter is written in the way that it provides implementation for a wrapped view - so it will either create a new child view (abstract getNewChildView) or reuse one (updateView) - and then adds it as a sub-view to cell item with the right padding/margin etc. (this provides automatically indenting in the tree).

So whenever you need to display something in your own way as a tree cell, you should build your own adapter (you can either extend SimpleStandardAdapter or build your own Adapter from the scratch in similar way to SimpleStandardAdapter and return appropriate view that you want to display as result of getNewChildView and updateView methods.

Both methods get TreeNodeInfo treeNodeInfo as parameter, so you can figure out which node of the tree you are about to render. The  type is - unfortunately - not changeable, I tried at the beginning to make a generic solution where you will be able to use any object type but failed at that, and it has to be Long. Probably it should be changed to reflect that.

So you will get the Long id from TreeNodeInfo that will identify the node, and the best way to use it is to use the Long value as index to some Map where you will keep reference to your node's object(s) and this way to know which data to render.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, Jarek, that gets me started.  Your help is much appreciated.